# Aurelia view inheritance gives odd behavior (typescript skeleton)

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I recently started trying out Aurelia (I'm new to Javascript and used to typed languages so I'm working from the typescript skeleton), and I ran into some odd issues with view inheritance that I don't understand.

I wanted to create two views with common functionality, which is why I wanted to create a common super class that both views could extend. This however caused unexpected behavior: when including both views in app.html, only one of the two shows, depending on the order of require statements.

I included a small minimal example below:

parent-view.ts

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';   

export abstract class ParentView {
    @bindable title: string;
}
```

child-a-view.html

```
<template><div>${title} A</div></template>
```

child-a-view.ts

```
import {ParentView} from './parent-view'

export class ChildAView extends ParentView {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

child-b-view.html

```
<template><div>${title} B</div></template>
```

child-b-view.ts

```
import {ParentView} from './parent-view'

export class ChildBView extends ParentView {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
export class App {}
```

app.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./child-a-view"></require>
    <child-a-view title="TitleA"></child-a-view>

    <require from="./child-b-view"></require>
    <child-b-view title="TitleB"></child-b-view>
</template>
```

This gives as output a page containing the text "TitleA B", while I'd expect two lines "TitleA A" and "TitleB B".

An alternative ordering of require statements in app.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./child-b-view"></require>
    <require from="./child-a-view"></require>
    <child-a-view title="TitleA"></child-a-view>
    <child-b-view title="TitleB"></child-b-view>
</template>
```

gives as output a page containing the text "TitleB A", while again I'd expect two lines "TitleA A" and "TitleB B".

Is this a bug in Aurelia, is it not allowed to inherit view classes, or am I doing something wrong here that causes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessarily a bug in Aurelia, more a general problem with JavaScript. But yes, inheritance is known to be problematic with custom elements and it is not recommended.

Aurelia strongly favors the composition over inheritance.

If you need to share common code between two or more ViewModels, try to approach it the other way around: make one ViewModel with the "common" code, and then you make the stuff variable that you would otherwise put in the child ViewModels.

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723769/aurelia-2-custom-elements-already-sharing-a-view-via-doing-almost-the-same-t/39727403#39727403)

And as @Alec Buchanan already pointed out, you can easily combine two views into one custom element (thereby achieving the same effect as inheriting the ViewModel) by using `compose`.

For instance:

**child-a-view.html**

```
<template><div>${title} A</div></template>
```

**child-b-view.html**

```
<template><div>${title} B</div></template>
```

**parent-view.ts**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';   

export class ParentView {
    @bindable title: string;
}
```

**parent-view.html**

```
<template>
    <compose view="./child-a-view.html"></compose>
    <compose view="./child-b-view.html"></compose>
</template>
```

This will automatically set the binding context of the child views to that of the parent view, meaning you can tread the child view html files as if parent-view.ts was their ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For my case that was indeed a great approach as almost all of the functionality was common for both views. It also helped for one of the next steps (I wanted a 'meta' component which can switch between child-a view and child-b view depending on the context). I do notice that for one specific view I'm currently having to cram a bit too much logic into the view as it doesn't fit into the common model. Would there be a way to e.g. add a second model to a view to address such a case?

Comment: There are several ways to address that, but what is the best way to go depends heavily on the logic you're referring to. I can take a look at it if you can put the models/views in question in a gist. https://gist.run/?id=883568d7c8e2add9ed393150100f4744

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to be trying to use these modules as custom elements? Could you not use the compose element to include each one?

eg

```
<template>
    <compose view-model="childAView" view="./child-a-view"></compose>
    <compose view-model="childBView" view="./child-b-view"></compose>
<template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The derived class need its own behavior. In your case, you need at least one decorator on the child class to tell Aurelia to inherit it right.